# echo different column values from different column from mysqli result

Tags: php, mysqli

Im making a comparative table of plans from the plans that I have added in mysql.

this is the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM webhosting 
INNER JOIN webhosting_cat
ON webhosting.cat = webhosting_cat.id
WHERE cat='$cat'
```

So per example, the "webhosting" table have this columns: plan, price, ssd_space

That mysql query will return 3 results and I want to have the option to print the results like `$row['plan'][0]`, `$row['plan'][1]` and `$row['plan'][2]`

Is that possible?

I use php 7.3 and MariaDB.

Comment: I don't exactly follow what you are trying to do. You should end up with results like `$row['plan']`, `$row['price']`, and `$row['ssd_space']` (along with whatever columns are available on the `webhosting_cat` table.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Im trying to echo the different per separate the 3 results of the mysql query, per example one column is named plan, but that have 3 results, planpro1, planpro2 and planpro3, that come inside.

Comment: I dont want to use a while() to print $row['plan'] per example

Comment: Fixed. I used $rows[$row['plan']] = $row; without a while

Comment: `while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { $rows[] = $row; }` lets you do `$rows[0]['plan']`

Answer (score 0):

As I do not know exactly how you would use your data, it may be most beneficial to regroup your data PHP.

```php
$arr = [[ 'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 1 ], [ 'foo' => 2, 'bar' => 2 ], [ 'foo' => 3, 'bar' => 3 ], [ 'foo' => 4, 'bar' => 4 ], [ 'foo' => 5, 'bar' => 5 ]];
function regroup($arr) {
    return array_reduce($arr, function($acc, $row) {
        foreach($row as $k => $v) $acc[$k][] = $v;
        return $acc;
    }, []);
}
print_r(regroup($arr));

// Array (
//     [foo] => Array
//              (
//             [0] => 1
//             [1] => 2
//             [2] => 3
//             [3] => 4
//             [4] => 5
//         )
//
//     [bar] => Array
//              (
//             [0] => 1
//             [1] => 2
//             [2] => 3
//             [3] => 4
//             [4] => 5
//         )
// )
```